# How do I automatically create users on GCE instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, user-management

I am trying to automatically create a system user linked to a service account, on instance startup. I could not find any info on this in the documentation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot create a user linked to a service account. There is no connection between VM OS users and service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a user linked to a service account. There is no connection between VM OS users and service accounts.[1](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)